# Queue Printing query

Tags: java, generics, queue

I have made a queue of a generic type. When I try to print out the contents of the two queues I have created the result is returned in the format of the last element in is the first element out (LIFO) instead of first in first out (FIFO). I can't seem to get it to print in the right order(FIFO). I use three separate classes. The MyNode class:

```
public class MyNode<T> {
    public T payload;
    public MyNode<T> next;
    public MyNode<T> previous;

    public MyNode(T payload) {
        this.payload = payload;
    }
    public MyNode(T payload, MyNode<T> next, MyNode<T> previous) {
        this.payload = payload;
        this.next = next;
        this.previous = previous;
    }

    public T getPayload() {
        return payload;
    }

    public MyNode<T> getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public MyNode<T> getPrevious() {
        return previous;
    }

    public void setPayload(T payload) {
        this.payload = payload;
    }

    public void setNext(MyNode<T> next) {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public void setPrevious(MyNode<T> previous) {
        this.previous = previous;
    }
}
```

The TestQueue class:

```
public class TestQueue {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyQueue<String> qStr = new MyQueue<String>();
        MyQueue<Integer> qInt = new MyQueue<Integer>();

        qStr.enqueue("hello");
        qStr.enqueue("world");
        System.out.println("Size of queue: " + qStr.size());
        System.out.println(qStr);
        System.out.println();

        qInt.enqueue(42);
        qInt.enqueue(3);
        System.out.println("Size of queue: " + qInt.size());
        System.out.println(qInt);
        System.out.println();

        qStr.dequeue();
        System.out.println(qStr);
        System.out.println();

        qInt.dequeue();
        System.out.println(qInt);
    }
}
```

The MyQueue class:

```
public class MyQueue<T> {
    public int size = 0;
    public MyNode<T> front = new MyNode<T>(null);
    public MyNode<T> back = new MyNode<T>(null);

    public void enqueue(T payload) {
        MyNode<T> newNode = new MyNode<T>(payload);
        newNode.next = front;
        front = newNode;
        if (isEmpty()) {
            back = newNode;
        }
        size++;
    }

    public T dequeue() {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        T payload = front.payload;
        front = front.getNext();
        size--;
        return payload;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return front == null;
    }

    public int size() {
        return size;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return front.getPayload().toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're inserting the new guys at the front of the queue instead of the back. The problem is with:

```
newNode.next = front;
//back.next = null;
front = newNode;
```

what you should do is:

```
 Node tmp = front;
 while (tmp.next != null) tmp = tmp.next;
 tmp.next = newNode;
```

I'll leave the updating of the previous field and size to you.